# Facebook plugin page in Rails Turbolinks doesn't load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

in my Rails app I am loading Facebook plugin page, but because of turbolinks it doesnt load each page (only sometimes). I tried [this script on this page](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html) , but now it never loads. What did I do?

I created facebook.coffee with this script:

```
$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless window.fbEventsBound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB?.XFBML.parse()
    )
  @fbEventsBound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length
    @fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if @fbRoot?
    if $('#fb-root').length
      $('#fb-root').replaceWith @fbRoot
    else
      $('body').append @fbRoot

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    status : true
    cookie : true
    xfbml  : true
```

And then in my application.js i just require it.

In view I have this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/mypage/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage/">MyPage</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Facebook plugin page isn't loading. Don't you know why? I was looking on appId, but in plugin page its not included.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with that script. What I know so far is that $.getScript() removes the query part of the URL and replaces it with a timestamp and that's why we get an invalid version error from Facebook's API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me ... Some sort of combination between Facebook's docs and the script on the page you linked

```
$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless window.fbEventsBound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB.XFBML.parse()
    )
  @fbEventsBound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length
    @fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if @fbRoot?
    if $('#fb-root').length
      $('#fb-root').replaceWith @fbRoot
    else
      $('body').append @fbRoot

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  ((d, s, id) ->
    js = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
    return if d.getElementById(id)
    js = d.createElement(s)
    js.id = id
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5"
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
  )(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    # appId : 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    status : true
    cookie : true
    xfbml : true
```

The difference is in the loadFacebookSDK function. Notice that as I commented in the question, $.getScript() removes the query/parameters part of the request.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I just already removed turbolinks from my app, because all other JS codes doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this question, I found this gist, which solves the problem: https://gist.github.com/6temes/52648dc6b3adbbf05da3942794b97a00

```
// FacebookSDK
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); // Replace 'facebook-jssdk' with your page id.

// Compatibility with Turbolinks 5
(function($) {
  var fbRoot;

  function saveFacebookRoot() {
    if ($('#fb-root').length) {
      fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach();
    }
  };

  function restoreFacebookRoot() {
    if (fbRoot != null) {
      if ($('#fb-root').length) {
        $('#fb-root').replaceWith(fbRoot);
      } else {
        $('body').append(fbRoot);
      }
    }

    if (typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null) { // Instance of FacebookSDK
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:request-start', saveFacebookRoot)
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', restoreFacebookRoot)
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

in turbolink 5, you just need to add data-turbolinks-permanent to the container
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#issuecomment-282997683

```
<div data-turbolinks-permanent id="fb-root"></div>
```